# XCTest target is not running after project renaming

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, unit-testing, xctest

Before writing unit tests using XCTest framework my project was renamed from "osxapplication" to "My Application" in project settings as shown in example on screenshot below:
http://jslim.net/images/posts/2015-01-08-how-to-rename-xcode-project-thoroughly/original.png

Also set "Product Name" to "My Application" in project settings.

Then I created new target with wizard and "My Application Tests" target was added to the project.

The problem is that when I run test (using menu Product->Test) it launches my product (NOT unit tests)

How to solve the problem above?

I use Xcode 6.2 and Yosemite 10.10.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the problem above by setting exact path for "Test Host" in build settings for unit tests target

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I'm just providing visual info to Sergio's answer. Also, for anyone who wants to take deeper dive to test, it is better to go to the source itself. The image was taken from apple's documentation at : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/05-running_tests.html